# What are these wooden posts?

Tags: furniture, tools

I am starting a tinker group for kids.

I have seen these wooden posts pictured in a number of tinkering setups, since they have pre-drilled holes and can be connected relatively easily by young children.  But what are they?! Someone I know said they are used in furniture building?

[image: picture of wooden strips and posts]

[image: picture of wooden posts]

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Easy to reproduce, given a table saw and a drill press...

Comment: I've never seen these before, if you're looking to buy them perhaps the best option is simply to ask the people who posted these or similar pictures where they got them. If you needed to make them, as @keshlam says these are easy enough to create, particularly if you buy the square-section wood to start. Then you only need to cut lengths and do the drilling. Creating the holes will be slow, tedious work regardless of the drill used but you just slog away and before you know it you'll be done. If you need tips on making your own modify this Question or ask a fresh one specifically about that.

Comment: Ikea's Ivar shelving standards have holes bored on one edge... that could be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, everyone.  I might be able to get access to a drill press, but not sure I could muster up the patience to drill all the holes that I need!  : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are known as [Gridbeam](http://www.gridbeam.com/woodproducts.html)

They are made from reclaimed wood and they also make an aluminium variety.

> We hand manufacture wood Gridbeam™ from 100% recycled douglas fir in
>   Northern California. Our location gives us access to the highest
>   quality recycled wood from nearby NorthCal Lumber, the largest wood
>   recycler in the United States.
>
> Our beautiful, straight grained, old growth douglas fir has the
>   highest strength to weight ratio of any structural wood and does not
>   dent or crush like softer woods.

[image: Douglas fir]
[image: Aluminium]